# automated test for a command line utility that opens a browser for login

Tags: selenium, go, selenium-webdriver, oauth-2.0

I'd like to write a test (preferably in Go) that tests a client app that logs in to server using a browser (using oauth2 PKCE grant type).

the command goes like this:

```
./myapp login --server-url=https://myserver.url
```

Next, a browser is opened at some server endpoint, and once auth is done (by entering a username and password), I get a message of success. The client app then caches `access token` to use it on future requests.

My question:
How can test this flow in automated test?
For example, I can run the command line from within the test, but how can I control or connect to the opened browser (with selenium for example)?

Answer (score 0):

You can script login into Oauth2 server and obtain a redirect URL and then invoke the app via this redirect URL.

Comment: I'm not sure how this tests the app login. I need to test that my app is able to open a browser, and then some username and password is fed (not sure how to automate this), and then oauth exchange is done, and browser is redirected to localhost that receives the access token.